# Need help understanding pointers in given code

Tags: pointers

```
FBYTE *d = (FBYTE*) dst; 
const FBYTE *s = (const FBYTE*) src;
 while(cnt >= sizeof(int)) {
                *(int*) d = *(int*) s;
                 d += sizeof(int);
                 s += sizeof(int);
                 cnt -= sizeof(int);
        }
```

I am new to C programming and I am unable to understand how the 4th line of the code is working

```
     *(int*) d = *(int*) s;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's just an absurdly complicated and awfully slow way of copying data instead of calling memcpy. On some mobile devices this will run _awfully_ slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole piece of code  is about copying the buffer in `src` to `dst`. The `while` loop iterates over `src`, and in each iteration copies a single `int`.

Let's examine the right hand side of the 4th line:

- `s` is a pointer to the area of source memory you want to copy.
- the first cast (`(int *)s`) means treating it as a pointer to `int`
- The deference  before it (`* (int *)s`) means take the value the point is pointing to.

The same applies to the left hand side of the expression.

So, basically, you're iterating over the `src` buffer, and in each iteration copying the **value** of the current `int` to `dst`.

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis takes precedence, so you are casting it to a pointer of type int and then you are retrieving the value (dereferencing) pointed by that pointer s and copying it to wherever d points to.

Answer (score 0):

d is a pointer. It is declared to be a pointer to an "FBYTE", whatever an FBYTE is - the programmer writing this needs to be slapped since char* or unsigned char* would have done the job just fine.

(int *)d is the same pointer, but the compiler is told that it is a pointer to an int.

When you have a pointer int* p, then an assignment *p = 5 for example assigns the number 5 to the int value that p points to. Here, (int*) d is a pointer to an int, so we also write a * in front of it, and * (int *)d = whatever assigns "whatever" to the int that this pointer points to.

So what the whole line does: Take the pointer s. Pretend that it is a pointer to int, not a pointer to FBYTE. Read the int that it points to. Take the pointer d. Pretend that it is a pointer to int, not a pointer to FBYTE. Write the int that you just read to the int that d points to.

Code like this shouldn't be written. It is a clear example of someone trying to be clever and failing. If you want to copy data, call memcpy or memmove. They will copy the data probably ten times faster. In this case, on an iPhone memcpy may be 1000 times faster in some situations (because the code fails to check that the pointers are aligned).